# Ionic CLI version 2.1.4 fails to generate page ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-cli

The ionic g page test fails to generate page and gives me the following error:

> ionic g page test

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '...\node_modules\ionic-angular\templates\page'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:856:18)
    at getTemplatesInDir (..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-generators\index.js:23931:65)
    at Generator.renderAndWriteTemplates (..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-generators\index.js:25309:
116)
    at ..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-generators\index.js:25304:26


ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '..\node_modules\ionic-angular\templates\page' (CLI v2.1.4)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v5.1.0
```

What is going wrong ???

Please HELP !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should re-install ionic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're running the command in directory other than the root directory.
Move to your project root and re-run the command.